# How can i mysql subquery limit?

Tags: mysql

```sql
SELECT demodetails.DemoId,
       demodetails.DemoName,
       demodetails.DemoSlug,
       imagedata.PostType,
       imagedata.Location
FROM demodetails,
     imagedata
WHERE demodetails.IsRemoved='False' in
    (SELECT 1
     FROM imagedata
     WHERE imagedata.ImageCatId = demodetails.DemoId
       AND imagedata.PostType='demo'
     LIMIT 1)
```

Comment: `demodetails.IsRemoved='False' in (SELECT 1` you can't both check if `IsRemoved` is False **and** it's in the subquery which will return `1` pick one of the two

Comment: Please make the exact query ..I'm new i couldn't find anything help

Comment: Explain what you're trying to do, what your database structure is like, and maybe some sample data with expected result from your query. It also is a good idea to read up on some good tutorials

Comment: want to show my table X all data and linking X table Id to Y table sub id match and pick only one data ....same id lot of data stored Y table but want to pick only first row 1 data